# Bluetooth and USB stop working on high CPU performance

Tags: usb, bluetooth

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with Kernel 4.9.35-040935 on System 76 laptop.

Recently, I am doing some intensive computations. However, I found that after the computation ran a little while and CPU was on high performance, my bluetooth and USB would suddenly stop working. The bluetooth manager just shutdown, cannot be enabled again. It's been several times in the past week. They would be back to normal after I rebooted the system.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Any excess temperature?

Comment: I didn't pay attention to the temperature. But it was warm and the fan was running loudly during the tasks. After a while, Bluetooth and USB stopped working.